# connect postgres sql server with wix

Tags: postgresql, velo

I have an postgres SQL server which I know everything of its (ip address, username, password, ....).

Now I want to create a website by Wix, then connect to that postgres SQL server to query.
I have read the instruction here (https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-integrate-your-google-cloud-mysql-or-postgres-database-with-your-wix-site),but since my database is not in Google cloud platform, I can not use this method. Except from this, I did not find other instructions.

To connect database on Wix, they need "endpoint URL" and "configuration".

- How can I get these information from my postgres SQL server?
- Do I need to install extra "something" to connect?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install anything extra. You might have to check your database security settings to ensure that Wix is allowed to read your data. For example, if you are using RDS (AWS) you should check the inbound / outbound security group rules to allow Wix queries.

The endpoint and config can also be checked from the RDS admin panel. The endpoint should look like like this:

**Endpoint**:
(database_name).************.(AWS_region).rds.amazonaws.com